# IBDesignable UIButton IB Render without IBInspectables

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

I have below code to create a custom IBDesignable UIButton. Note that I do not have any IBInspectables since I do not need any. I want all my custom buttons to be same.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class ShButton: UIButton {

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self._setup()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self._setup()
}


override func awakeFromNib() {
    self._setup()
}

override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    self._setup()
}

private func _setup(){
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    super.drawRect(rect)
}

deinit {
}

}
```

There are two problems:

1. ShButton Class does not show in Custom Class dropdown in IB, I have to manually type it and also provide Module name. I also noticed that there is no "Designables Up to Date" indicator showing here either, which shows in many tutorials on the subject.
2. It does not render in IB. However when I run the project in Simulator, it renders correctly. Am I missing anything to make it render in IB?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No Sorry, I could not

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you running? The code you provided runs fine on Xcode 7.2, after making `required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` fallible by changing it to `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm still kind of an iOS newb, but I had a similar situation, and this worked fine for me:

```swift
@IBDesignable class ShButton: UIButton {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self._setup()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self._setup()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        self._setup()
    }

    private func _setup(){
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

This allowed me to set a default `cornerRadius` on a button without having to use an `IBInspectable`, and worked in both the storyboard and at runtime.

EDIT: Updated answer